# what is /rostopic_10245_1493704203398

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`/rostopic_10245_1493704203398` appears when I run `rosnode list`. Is it by default? The list of number affixed are random or not?

And it has subscriptions of my node.The relevant info of it presents as follows:

```
Node [/rostopic_10245_1493704203398]
Publications: 
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]

Subscriptions: 
 * /odometry/filtered [nav_msgs/Odometry]

Services: 
 * /rostopic_10245_1493704203398/set_logger_level
 * /rostopic_10245_1493704203398/get_loggers


contacting node http://idriver-ThinkPad-E450:42951/ ...
Pid: 10245
Connections:
 * topic: /rosout
    * to: /rosout
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /odometry/filtered
    * to: /ekf_navigation_node (http://idriver-ThinkPad-E450:39280/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
```

Can someone enlighten it to me?I do appreciate your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260828/what-is-/rostopic_10245_1493704203398/) by [DaDaLee](https://answers.ros.org/users/30176/dadalee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rostopic_10245_1493704203398 is an anonymous rostopic name. The anonymous means it apprend numbers to the node name so multiple nodes can live at the same time.

Also, rostopic is the tool used to read/write manually on topics.  (rostopic echo, pub,...)

---

Originally posted by [AlexisTM](https://answers.ros.org/users/29858/alexistm/) with karma: 31 on 2017-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DaDaLee](https://answers.ros.org/users/30176/dadalee/) on 2017-05-02**:
Thank you for your reasonable proposal.So does it mean /rostopic*******(prefixed number) appears whatever node I run and it carries the data being published?